# Keep only most recent rows by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having this table

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKINGS
    ([RES_ID] varchar(4), [ATTENDANCE_DATE] datetime, [AUTOID] int);

INSERT INTO BOOKINGS
    ([RES_ID], [ATTENDANCE_DATE], [AUTOID])
VALUES
    ('A001', '2018-01-01 00:00:00', 1),
    ('A002', '2018-01-01 00:00:00', 2),
    ('A003', '2018-01-01 00:00:00', 3),
    ('A001', '2018-01-02 00:00:00', 4),
    ('A002', '2018-01-02 00:00:00', 5),
    ('A003', '2018-01-02 00:00:00', 6),
    ('A002', '2018-01-03 00:00:00', 7),
    ('A003', '2018-01-03 00:00:00', 8);
```

I would like to remove all rows with `id='A001'` since at the most recent date, there is no reservation (i.e. was canceled).

I have tried this:

```
with cte as
(
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by [res_id]
                      order by  [ATTENDANCE_DATE] desc) rn
  from BOOKINGS
)
DELETE FROM cte where rn > 1;
```

But this keeps the most recent line for `'A001'` (id=4) and I don't want that.

Expected output is:

```
A002    2018-01-03 00:00:00.000 7
A003    2018-01-03 00:00:00.000 8
```

Comment: It is not clear why id 4 should not be there. How you recognize that id A001 was canceled?

Comment: Because at the most recent date there is no res_id='A001'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to compare the most recent date for each `resid` to the most recent date overall.  You can do this using window functions:

```
with todelete as (
      select b.*,
             max(attendance_date) over (partition by res_id) as max_ad_resid,
             max(attendance_date) over () as max_ad
      from bookings b
     )
delete from todelete
    where max_ad_resid < max_ad;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply delete like this

```
delete
from BOOKINGS
where ATTENDANCE_DATE != (
  select max(ATTENDANCE_DATE) from BOOKINGS
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
        DELETE FROM BOOKINGS WHERE
    [ATTENDANCE_DATE] <= (SELECT MAX([ATTENDANCE_DATE]) FROM BOOKINGS where RES_ID = 'A001')
```

This gets the max date for RES_ID A001 (no reservations) and deletes all entries equal or before that date.